# Do the gravitational wave moves the Ligo's mirror or the photon in the laser beam?

Tags: laser, gravitational-waves, ligo

On [NASA website](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/gravitational-waves/en/) there is an animation showing a signal is detected when the gravitational wave shifts the mirrors about, causing the laser to go out of phase. Do gravitational wave actually shifts the mirrors or the photon in the laser beam? btw the mirror weights about 40kg hanging from a ceiling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mirrors move relative to the structures around them such as the vacuum chamber; the tunnel; the ground. The reason is that they are hanging so that they are free to move in the horizontal direction, whereas the structure of the long tubes etc. is constrained by its own internal forces (provided by electromagnetic and quantum effects). The wave is much too weak to squeeze the solid structures of the tunnel by even a tiny fraction of the (already small) distance through which the mirrors move.

The mirrors are deliberately made as heavy as feasible, because the gravitational force increases in proportion to the mass. One might equally say that gravity gets to grips directly on the acceleration, whereas other physical influences such as electromagnetism produce smaller acceleration for larger mass. So a large mass is good to make gravitational effects larger compared to other effects.

Comment: Isn't the displacement independent of the mirror's mass due to equivalence principle?  Their high mass is for noise reduction as far as I know.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Correct on both counts; it is exactly what I said (but perhaps I did not say it clearly).

Comment: I listen something about GW-s but they talked about perpendicular action  to spacetime by a GW 1.on a vertical and horizontal axis and 2. on diagonals but nothing about action in direction of propagation of the wave....

Comment: The mirrors are made as heavy as possible to reduce noise, not for the gravitation force.  The gravitational forces are amplified by the length of the tunnel/arms ... the longer the tunnels the more the gravity wave space contraction is evident.

Comment: @PhysicsDave It is signal to noise ratio that is important.  Any noisy force not proportional to mass stays constant as mass goes up; the grav force (hence signal) goes up in proportion to mass (as well is in proportion to tunnel length). If instead you measure in terms of acceleration then the noise goes down with mirror mass and the signal stays constant.

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational waves do not move Ligo's mirrors by a measurable amount, if at all.  Gravitational waves expand and contract space which changes the proper lengths of Ligo's two arms.  Ligo's test masses are free to move in the same direction shown in interferometer animations only because that's the direction needing the most isolation from noise; not so they can be moved by gravitational waves.  If you only needed to measure the movement of a test mass, why would you put your measuring instrument four kilometers away?  Animations that move mirrors are OK to demonstrate how an interferometer works, but they don't explain how Ligo works.  I'll grant that it's hard to create an interferometer animation where the mirrors don't move but the distance to the mirrors changes!

Laser photons are unchanged by gravitational waves.  Except for spending a very very tiny bit more or less time bouncing back and forth in the expanded and contracted space.

Comment: Interesting that space is contracted very very slightly ... the EM field dimensions must be contracted as well but the photons maintain their properties.